# Aspect pointcut to use annotation property

Tags: java, annotations, aspectj

There is a TraceAspect which should execute some logging on any method or class (all methods of class) annotated with Trace annotation.

```
@Aspect
public class TraceAspect {    
    @Pointcut("(@annotation(Trace) || @within(Trace)) && execution(* *(..))")
    void allAnnotated(){}

    @Around("allAnnotated()")
    public Object trace(final ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        // doing some stuff here
    }
}
```

and the annotation:

```
@Target({ElementType.CONSTRUCTOR, ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Trace {
    boolean enabled() default true;
}
```

I need to modify pointcut so that all methods/classes that have Trace.enabled setted to false to be skipped (not considered as join points).

```
@Pointcut("allAnnotated() && Trace.enabled")
```

or (if its not possible) at least have that Annotation and its value in the advise so that I could check for property and skip logging...

Comment: I think it should be definitely possible to have that pointcut at compile time, because your annotations are already containing property value at compile time. Otherwhise I'll have additional if statement executed on any aspect execution (which is not good)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at 'annotation value matching' in https://eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/README-160.html

What you can do is:

`@Pointcut("execution(@Trace(enabled=true) * *(..)) || execution(* (@Trace(enabled=true) *).*(..))")`

The first is method level annotations, the second is type level annotations. The syntax for embedding values in @annotation/@within isn't there yet (so you can't do `@annotation(Trace(enabled=true))`

Comment: Whenever I read something you write I inevitably learn something. And everytime I think I know a lot about AspectJ I realise that I do not know enough yet. Thanks again. :-)